# Check if it the value on X table matches with value Y table and add to a different table the result of that two together

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So, Let's say I have this table [Movements]:

```
Date      Date of value description of movement Cost  
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   BPI Taxes               1000€
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   Transference            2000€
12-02-2019 12-01-2019   Payments                2000€
```

Second table [Documents]:

```
  Date       Document Number   Client  Cost   
01-03-2019    ADT19.30           X     1000€
01-03-2019    ADT20.30           y     2000€
01-03-2019    ADT20.30           z     2000€
```

Third Table [Reference]

```
   Date   Date of value description of movement Client               Cost  
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   BPI Taxes               Doc. Number of X     1000€
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   Transference            Doc. Number of Y     2000€
12-02-2019 12-01-2019   Payments                Doc. Number of Z     2000€
```

Result Table:

```
 Date   Date of value   description of movement   Client        Cost  
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   BPI Taxes                 ADT19.30     1000€
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   Transference              ADT20.30     2000€
12-02-2019 12-01-2019   Payments                  ADT20.30     2000€
```

My goal with this is, to save user's time by doing a program that matches the "Client" name(second table) in the Client column of the Third table and replaces the name with the "document number" value. Basically, if the second table, column client, the names, matches with the Client column of the third table then insert in a new table a new record ... I hope I made Clear it's a little hard to explain

UPDATE
Query that I tried so Far:

```
 Select Reference.[Date of movement], Reference.[Date of value], Reference.[Description], Document.[document Number], Reference.[Cost]
 From Reference
 INNER JOIN Document On Reference.[client] = Document.[document Number];
```

UPDATE
Turns out and I understand it wrong, Im supposed to do this: 
So, Let's say I have this table [Movements]:

```
Date      Date of value description of movement     Cost  
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   BPI Taxes of x              1000€
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   Transference of y           2000€
12-02-2019 12-01-2019   Payments of z               2000€
```

Second table [Documents]:

```
  Date       Document Number   Client  Cost   
01-03-2019    ADT19.30           X     1000€
01-03-2019    ADT20.30           y     2000€
01-03-2019    ADT20.30           z     2000€
```

Result Table:

```
 Date   Date of value   description of movement   Client       Cost  
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   BPI Taxes of x            ADT19.30     1000€
12-01-2019 12-01-2019   Transference of y         ADT20.30     2000€
12-02-2019 12-01-2019   Payments of z             ADT20.30     2000€
```

Im supposed to, by the "description of movement" find in the string if it contains the name in that string or not and if it contains insert in database 
 the result table

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a `JOIN`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The `C#` and `asp.net` tags are interesting. Are you trying to build an application to display the Result table? Or are you trying to make an actual new table in sql server?

Comment: @dvo I'm doing this program on asp.net c#, and yeah I'm trying to display the result table

Comment: @Larnu Not too much, Im trynna figuring out how I'm gonna start

Comment: @PuppyPoop A `JOIN` is what you're looking for in SQL Server. Try to write a join statement for your case, then edit your post with your attempt. Do you also need help displaying the table in asp? If so, post your attempt of that code as well.

Comment: how to write a `JOIN` and how to display data (from SQL Server) using C# are very different questions, @dvo . I would suggest the OP asks 2 different questions for those. The answers to both questions are completely unrelated, and asking the questions in the same post would push this to being to broad (it's already unclear what they are asking).

Comment: @Larnu That's fair. My guess is he is only stuck on the `join` but can display the data in asp - but yes. A separate question is better I suppose.

Comment: @PuppyPoop This [w3 schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) might help you. It shows a nice graphic of the different types of `JOIN`s

Comment: @dvo I think Join Will not gonna help or at least it doesn't seems that it will do the work, cause I want to match the values of the second table with the thirth

Comment: @PuppyPoop post your attempt please. You are going to have to do some string manipulation on your `Document Number of XYZ` to get the value you need to join on.

Comment: @dvo Im trying to do in sql first to apply in asp.net after but I'm doing something wrong...* Edited the question *

Comment: @dvo By doing that query Im basically replacing all client names with all number of documents names... The query isnt kinda searching trought the value and see where it matches and where it doesnt

Comment: @PuppyPoop If your Client values in the Reference table are actually in the format `Document Number of X`, you need to extract only the Client value (Remove "Document Number of ") using `SUBSTRING` or something similar and then match that with the Client value from the Documents table. The select piece looks good.

Comment: @dvo That's a good idea, but I'm wondering what to do in this case: "TPA - BILHETES JORGE - 19/03" 9/5000
remembering that I just want the name in this case "JORGE"

Comment: @dvo Cause in the post I did an exemple to make the things simple but I will substring do the job?

Comment: @PuppyPoop This is getting muddy. Why not just store the actual client value in the reference table? Then you can join value for value, not a weird manipulation of a value for a value that may or may not be exact. Is this possible?

Comment: @dvo unfortunately no, cause this is for a company, so I can't really change the excel file

Comment: @PuppyPoop The only option is to manipulate based on some standardized format. Or some other common value between two tables you can join on.

Comment: @dvo Look the new update that I did

Comment: @PuppyPoop It's still really hard to join those tables. You're matching a non-unique string with another non-unique string so your joins could get messed up. Ex: If two clients have the same name or even similar name (Client A's and Client A's Towing). You need something unique in both tables to join on.